# Is it possible to fetch email address of facebook restaurant (or any individual category) page owners?

Tags: php, facebook, fetch, email-address

Is it possible to fetch email address for facebook restaurant (or any individual category) page owners?

I want email addresses of all the restaurant page owners.

Comment: I'm pretty sure it isn't, and a good thing too as I can't conceive of any reason to do this that doesn't involve sending spam.

Comment: then is it possible to get listed of all the restaurant categorized facebook pages?

Comment: I'm sure all email spammers would love email addresses of every restraunt owner too.

Answer (score 2):

This isn't possible unless the users in question authorise your app and give you the `email` extended permission to access their email and the `manage_pages` extended permission so you can see which pages they manage.

There's no way to determine the admins of a page just based on the page ID and as 'Quentin' says there would be almost no policy compliant or legal reasons to have such a feature in the API

Comment: then is it possible to get listed of all the restaurant categorized facebook pages?

Comment: No, the API doesn't support page searching by category, just by name as far as I'm aware